# React component using previous state after updating

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a form with two input boxes. On form submission, I have to take these values and concat them to an array. Once done, I need to display them.

I used states for this however, I'm facing a weird issue: every time I update a state, I cannot get the updated state in the function.

```
const [a, updateA] = useState('1')

// ...

// Assume this is called when form is submitted
const updation = (event) => {
  updateA(event.target.value)
  console.log(a) // prints 1 instead of the new value
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Value of state is updated only during next render - so it's expected behavior.

Comment: You are logging its closure value... Its purely Javascript not React related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState()` is asynchronous. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately. `useState()` does not always immediately update the component. Think of `useState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component.
So you can not see the result immediately inside the method.you can use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of a
}, [a]);
```

and

```
    const [a, updateA] = useState('1')
    
    
    const updation = (event) => {
      updateA(event.target.value)
      console.log(a) // prints 1 
    }

console.log(a) // prints updated Value
```